# re-install 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I need to reinstall 12.04 from scratch and can't figure out how to do it.

I had been running Ubuntu 11.?.  When I upgraded to 12.04, I found that I could not open PDFs and most video files will not play.

You help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this:  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04/

If you want to open PDF files, go to LibreOffice Draw> File > Open and then select PDF from the dropdown list.

Because media codecs for most of the media file formats have proprietary licenses, it is not included in the standard installation.  To make those media formats work, search for `ubuntu-restricted-extras` in the ubuntu software center and install it.  This install all the proprietary codecs.

And if you really want to reinstall Ubuntu, select "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" while installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Why so difficult? Just booting from Ubuntu LiveCD would suffice, `gparted` is on the LiveCD... although it's easier to do everything right from the Ubuntu installer. So "1. Install Ubuntu normally" should be enough :)

Comment: Oh is it?  I never knew that.  Thanks for pointing it out!